# JSON simple live search not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a simple live search setup I can't troubleshoot. I am new to JSON but fairly hapy with the html and jquery, however i will include all code here. There are no errors, the results just simply don't show as I type. Here is the html first:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>JSON live search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="searcharea">
    <label for="search">Live search</label>
    <input type="search" name="search" id ="search" placeholder="start typing.." />
    </div>
    <div id="update"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the js:

```
 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    output += '<li>';
    output += '<h2>' + val.name + '</h2>';
    output += '</li>';
});
output += '</ul'>;
$('#update').html(output);
 });
```

I have structured the JSON data file in the following way:

```
 {
 "businesses":[
 {"name":"LJMU","contacts":[{"contacts":"con1"},{"contacts":"con2"},{"contacts":"con3"}]},
 {"name":"Bobs bricks","contacts":[{"contacts":"con1"},{"contacts":"con2"},{"contacts":"con3"}]},
 {"name":"Apple","contacts":[{"contacts":"con1"},{"contacts":"con2"},{"contacts":"con3"}]},
 ]
 }
```

I know it's a pain but can anyone suggest why I'm not seeing results?

Comment: Well you never attached a keypress listener to the textbox....Or you did not show that part...

Comment: I actually had onkeyup="script.js" initially but that didn't work either

Comment: JS 101: create a function with the code to execute, attach an event handler, call the function in the event handler.

Comment: onkeyup="getJSON(this.data)" ?

Comment: can you provide a solution or answer or even help, instead of abuse perhaps?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt `output += '<h2>' + val.name + '</h2>';`

be

`output += '<h2>' + val.businesses.name + '</h2>';`

Comment: It should be `val.businesses[0].name`, but I think there's bigger issues.

Comment: The OP is not calling the code so yeah, there is bigger issues!

Answer (score 0):

Your json object(`data`) contains one property `businesses` which is array. so you must use in `$.each` not `data`, but `data.businesses`

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
    $.each(data.businesses, function(key, val) {
        output += '<li>';
        output += '<h2>' + val.name + '</h2>';
        output += '</li>';
    });
    output += '</ul'>;
    $('#update').html(output);
});
```

Comment: FYI: Problem is more than the looping...OP is not even calling this